# What is the "big theta" order of the solution of T_n = T_(n/2) + log n, n > 0?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, recursion, master-theorem

What method(s) could be used to solve this? I am still new to this stuff and would appreciate detailed justification for every step as well as some intuition and the examination of all possible viable methods to go about this, not just one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that $n$ is a power of $2$.

By unrolling $T(n) = T(n/2) + \log n$ you get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\log n + \log \frac{n}{2} + \log \frac{n}{4} + \log \frac{n}{8} + \dots &= \log  n + ( \log n - 1 ) + (\log n - 2) + (\log n - 2) + \dots \\
 & =  \sum_{i=0}^{\log n} (\log n - i) = \sum_{i=0}^{\log n} i=\frac{(\log n)(\log n + 1)}{2}\\
& = \Theta(\log^2 N).
\end{align*}
$$

---

This even easier to see if you substitute $n = 2^k$ and define $S(k) = T(2^k)$:
$$
S(k) =T(2^k) = T(2^k-1) + \log 2^k = S(k-1) +k.
$$
Unrolling shows that $S(k) = \sum_{i=1}^k i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} = \Theta(k^2) = \Theta(\log^2 n)$.

---

Otherwise you could use the master theorem. For $a=1$, $b=2$, $k=1$, and $f(n) = \log n$ you have:
$$
T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)
$$
and $n^{\log_a b} \cdot \log^k n = \Theta(f(n))$. Then $T(n) = n^{\log_a b} \cdot \log^{k+1} n = 1 \cdot \log^2 n = \Theta(\log^2 n)$.

Comment: Thanks! Though I believe in the first method it should be logn+1 instead of logn-1 (sum of terms of an arithmetic sequence, where the number of terms is logn+1 and the first+last terms = logn+0 = logn). Also for the 2nd method: k(k+1)/2 instead of k(k-1)/2.